# Wordpress: Change "older posts" style without messing the theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, coding-style, wordpress-theming

In my blog, the text that says "Older posts" is written in gray, and very invisible. I would like to change its style.

I can do that through the php files, but then, every time I update the theme, I'll have to redo that. So I need a way to do it in a way that makes it independent of updates.

Thank you for any efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-css/
And Add the CSS code for the pagination.
If you have google chrome just right click over the Older Posts Inspect Element
See the CSS class used by it and add the CSS code for that class in the Plugin after installation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to style the link with CSS but it is difficult to show you without any code segments provided in your question.

If you use chrome developer tools, simply click on the element, find its class name and reference it in your style sheet.

I've provided an example below which is taken from another wordpress theme, but I cant guarantee it will be the same as your own:

```
<div class="post-more">
   <span class="read-more"><a title="Read more" href="http://www.website.com">Read more</a></span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.post-more a {
color: #000000;  /*New Colour*/
}
```